# Wordpress interactive map

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

Currently I have an interactive map using Google Maps on my personal website (Wordpress): [guidoleurs.org](http://guidoleurs.org) (under 'projects'), but it is not working correctly on mobile devices. So I am looking for a free alternative to create an interactive map that gives me the opportunity to add markers, with linked lightboxes for small content.

Suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IDEAL Interactive Map". Its a Wordpress Plugin:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ideal-interactive-map/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a *free* alternative then try [MapSVG Lite WordPress map plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mapsvg-lite-interactive-vector-maps/) - tested & works good on mobile devices.